# Eclipse - sharing project directory with multiple users

Tags: eclipse

We are trying to set up Eclipse so that two users can share the same project directory on our server.  Is this possible?  Every time we try, it creates a new folder and project.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible. Eclipse only supports a single user accessing a workspace (not just a project) at a time.

Use a source control system such as Git or SVN to share code. Eclipse supports many such systems and has extensive sharing support in the 'Team' menus.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use source control.

Sharing the actual workspace or the files with different eclipse instance is a recipe for trouble.

An easy way to do this would be to install git on your machine and also on his machine.  Eclipse actually already has git in it ready to go so you probably dont need to install anything.

The one with the files locally will create a repo locally on his computer and commit the files to it.
Next you want to init a new empty repository on a shared folder and push your local chances to this as you would to github for example.
Your partner can then git clone from this repository to his machine and work locally.

Each of you will develop on your own copy and commit your changes locally.  You will share your changes by pushing your commits in that central repo and pulling from it to get changes from your partner.

You could also just open an account on [GitHub](https://github.com/), [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) (there are many others too) and use that instead of a shared folder.  big advantage with these services is that they will be available from anywhere.

Comment: while your response is valid, it may not always be the answer. The original question asks for sharing a single directory. So both users might be on the same computer. As in my case. I have multiple logins, and need to access the code which runs against a single web server on the computer.